# Permutation test in R

Tags: r

I want to check whether two variables are correlated or not after breaking the association between those two variables. And I am supposed to do it using permutation and using the kendall correlation coefficient. I am not sure if I am doing it the right way. Below is my code.

```
### This is original observed data
observed <- cor(myData$gene_dens,myData$qp.site,method = "kendall") 
plot(myData$gene_dens,myData$qp.site,main=paste("Corelation = ",observed))

### I am doing permuation here to break the association between the two variables I am looking at
perm = function(dataframe)
{

result1 = sample(dataframe$gene_dens,size = length(myData),replace = FALSE)

  return(result1)

}

###I am using 10000 replicates because I want to make a null distribution so that I don't have to rely on the assumptions of the normal distribution
result = replicate(10000,perm(myData)) 

### myData is the vector containing the entire data of the csv file.

hist(result)

pvalue <- (sum(result < observed) + sum(result > observed))/length(result)
```

Comment: but do you think I am calculating the pvalue the right way? I am not sure how to do it while using kendall coefficient and Permutation.

Comment: Ok Thankyou. I'll see what I can do here. Thanks :)